# Flex DataGrid: Adding an item listener to a cell to listen for ITEM_EDIT_BEGIN in another cell of the same row

Tags: apache-flex, addeventlistener, flex-datagrid

I'm a little stumped on how I should go about doing something.

I have a FlexDataGrid with a bunch of columns. One of the columns has an ItemRenderer for it. I want all the cells in this column to listen for an event. The event I want the to listen for is when someone begins editing a cell in the same row that the ItemRenderered cell is in.

So I have this code in my ItemRenderer which gets applied to each cell in the column:

```
this.addEventListener(FlexDataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_BEGINNING, showPopUp);
```

When showPopUp is called, a button will appear under this ItemRenderer.

The problem is, I don't know how I can make that eventListener work. How can I make this item renderer know when an ITEM_EDIT_BEGINNING event is happening in a different cell?

I'm completely stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify: mx or Spark? Also there is no such thing as a `FlexDataGridEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item renderer is actually a different component, so if you are dispatching them with the this keyword, they are not being seen by the other cells / item renderers.

Probably a bit more involved than you were expecting, but this is how you'd accomplish something like that

1) You will want to create a custom event that you can pass the row number with.  Something like this will work:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class EditRowEvent extends Event
    {
        public function EditRowEvent(type:String, rowEditingIn:Number, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            rowEditing = rowEditingIn;
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        public var rowEditing : Number;
    }
}
```

2) you need to dispatch when editing it to something all the item renders can see.  Something like the parent grid:

```
DataGrid(this.parentDocument).dispatchEvent( new EditRowEvent( 'beginEdit', this_renderers_row ) );
```

3) You need to listen for this event on the parent as well (do this when the item renderer is initialized) :

```
protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent=null):void
        {
            DataGrid(this.parentDocument).addEventListener( 'beginEdit' , handleEditOnRow );
        }
```

4) handle what you want to happen when that editing starts on the row of that particular item renderer

```
        public function handleEditOnRow ( event : EditRowEvent ) : void {
            if( this_renderers_row == event.rowEditing ){
                // code to execute when someone starts editing this row!
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Nate! I just have a couple questions about what you showed above:
1.) In your #2, where is this code going to be? Is this in the Custom Renderer Class or my DataGrid?
2.) Same for #3, is this the same location as #2?
3.) And I'm fairly certain your #4 goes in the Renderer correct?

And as for the "this_renderers_row", is there a quick way to get that?

Again, thanks for the help! This is making it clearer for me for sure.

Comment: 2,3,4 are all going to go into your renderer actually.  The row for the renderer you're going to get from somewhere, most likely your data (like the array index of your collection, etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nate! It all helps a lot!